# Changing the values in a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have an UNBALANCED dataset containing five fields like:

```
a_code  b_code sector  year  value 
1        2      15     1970  1000   
2        3      16     1971  2900
3        2      15     1970  3900
```

I want to create a 4-dimensional matrix in MATLAB for the "value" field. So I want to have a value field in a matrix such as `M(a_code,b_code,sector,year) = value`. I have 75 `a_code`, 75 `b_code`, 19 sectors and 45 years. So a NaN matrix is (75,75,19,45).

Since my dataset is not balanced (for example I don't have a value for `a_code = 3`, `b_code = 1`, `sector = 15`, `year = 1970`), I don't have a value for each (`a_code`, `b_code`, sector, year) combination. For the unavailable values, I want to have NaN. I know how to create a 4-dimensional matrix with NaN values, but how do I replace these NaN values with the ones in my dataset?

Probably I should write a loop, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some simple code to fulfill your requirements:

```
D= [1 2 15 1970 1000; 2 3 16 1971 2900; 3 2 15 1970 3900];
m= min(D(:, 1: end- 1))- 1;
shape= max(D(:, 1: end- 1))- m+ 1;

X= NaN(shape);
for k= 1: size(D, 1)
    n= D(k, 1: end- 1)- m;
    X(sub2ind(shape, n(1), n(2), n(3), n(4)))= D(k, end);
end
X(1, 1, 1, 1) %=> 1000
X(2, 2, 2, 2) %=> 2900
X(3, 1, 1, 1) %=> 3900
```

You may like to elaborate more on your specific situation, there may exists more suitable approaches. For example from your question, its not quite so clear why you need to have your data represented as a 4D array.

Comment: Basically I have a data set including a_code b_code, sector, year, and values. But the problem is this dataset is not balanced, meaning that I don't have value for each a,b, sector and year combination. So I am trying to construct a matrix which will show both available and unavailable(NaN) a,b,sector and year combinations.

Comment: @ozlem: First as a side note: in my answer the vector `m` is 'figured out' from the `data set`, but probably it actually should be defined by the user. For the main topic; I still can't see any real benefices to represent your data as 4D-array. Please elaborate more on the further processing you are planning to do with your `data set`? Essentially, what are the (assumed) advantages of 4D-array representation compared to matrix (2D-array) representation?

Comment: Honestly, creating a 4D matrix was the first thing that I could think of. I am sure there is a better way. What I want to do is to create a matrix from the table above such as M= [Na 1000 Na; Na Na Na; Na 3900 Na]. Of course this is only for sector=15 and year=1970. I will do that for each year and sector. So I thought that creating a 4d matrix is the best way?

Comment: @ozlem: Hmm, Please still elaborate us more on your requirements to further process the data set? Well, you see, perhaps your 4D-array representation eventually is the most reasonable one, but it's hard to say before you explain the true processing needed ;-). Thanks

Comment: I want to do that because at the end I will do interpolation in order to complete the missing values.

Comment: @ozlem: Aha, that's totally different beast then. Please keep us informed how that eventually works out. But meanwhile if you find my answer valuable at all, consider to accept it then. Thanks